# Extracting text file information via command line/script

Tags: regex, string, perl, awk, sed

I'd like to extract only certain information from a block of text. I have had great luck with asking the StackOverflow community for their expertise assistance, especially with tricky topics (RegEx, perl, sed, awk).

The text is output from a `tshark` command that I would like to manipulate and print out to avoid unnecessary information.

Any help would be appreciated. I am currently learning the ways of the aforementioned topics, but it's slow going!

Any script or command help to achieve the following output will be seriously helpful.

Original:

```
                                                     Host 1            Host 2            Total            Relative         Duration
Host 1                   Host 2                Frames     Bytes  Frames     Bytes  Frames     Bytes        Start
192.168.0.14         <-> 192.168.0.13            3898   4872033    1971    120545    5869   4992578     0.001886000       283.6363
192.168.0.162        <-> 192.168.0.71               2      1992       2      1992       4      3984   176.765198000        77.0542
192.168.0.191        <-> 192.168.0.150              3      2988       0         0       3      2988   199.319020000        59.7055
192.168.0.227        <-> 192.168.0.157              3      2988       0         0       3      2988   197.013283000        76.7197
192.168.0.221        <-> 192.168.0.94               3      2988       0         0       3      2988   196.312847000        59.7065
192.168.0.75         <-> 192.168.0.58               2      1992       1       996       3      2988   191.995706000        59.7121
224.0.0.252          <-> 192.168.0.13               3       207       0         0       3       207   180.521299000         0.0536
192.168.0.191        <-> 192.168.0.50               1       996       2      1992       3      2988   173.452130000        59.6849
192.168.0.41         <-> 192.168.0.13               3      2988       0         0       3      2988   167.180087000        76.6960
192.168.0.206        <-> 192.168.0.153              1       996       1       996       2      1992   270.528070000         4.4070
```

Desired:

```
Host 1     Host 2     Total Bytes
x.x.x.x    x.x.x.x    N
x.x.x.x    x.x.x.x    N
x.x.x.x    x.x.x.x    N
```

Comment: Did you really want to print `x.x.x.x` and `N`? If you're not going to provide a problem description, you should at the very least provide acceptable expected results.

Comment: No, I was substituting "x.x.x.x" for an actual IP address, and "N" as the Number of bytes in the conversation. My bad for not clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your output is in *filename*:

```
sed 's/ \+/ /g' filename | tail -n +3 | cut -f1,3,9 -d ' ' | sed 's/ /\t/g' | sort -r -n -k3
```

- replace multiple spaces with a single one, for tokenizing
- discard the first two header lines
- project columns 1, 3, and 9
- replace spaces with tabs to have columns back
- sort desc by total bytes

output:

```
192.168.0.14    192.168.0.13    4992578
192.168.0.162   192.168.0.71    3984
192.168.0.75    192.168.0.58    2988
192.168.0.41    192.168.0.13    2988
192.168.0.227   192.168.0.157   2988
192.168.0.221   192.168.0.94    2988
192.168.0.191   192.168.0.50    2988
192.168.0.191   192.168.0.150   2988
192.168.0.206   192.168.0.153   1992
224.0.0.252     192.168.0.13    207
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '
 BEGIN { printf "%-15s %-15s %s\n",  "Host 1", "Host 2", "Total Bytes" }
 NR>2  { printf "%-15s %-15s %11s\n", $1, $3, $9 }
' file
```

Adjust the output-field widths as needed.

- The `BEGIN` block is used to print the output header line.
- `NR > 2` ensures that the input header lines are skipped.
- `printf` is used with field-width specifiers create column-aligned output.

  - a `-` before the width specifier indicates left-aligned output (e.g.,`%-15s`; without it, the value is right-aligned (e.g., `%11s`)

Answer (score 2):

in perl:

```
tshark | perl -lane 'print join "\t", ($F[0], $F[2], $F[8])'
```

the `-a` option splits each line of stdin into an array called `@F`. the column numbers don't correspond well to the array index numbers because `-a` splits by space by default. you can set the delimiter with `-F` if you like.

`-F` would help get the headers aligned correctly too, but to just skip the misaligned headers, add `next if $. < 3;` before `print` to skip the first two lines

Comment: `$F[0], $F[2], $F[8]` better written `@F[0,2,8]`.